# Nested accordion (accordion within accordion within accordion and so on...)

Tags: angular

My Json response is like this

```
  [  
   {  
      "name":"A",
      "price":50,
      "children":[  
         {  
            "name":"AA",
            "price":150,
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "name":"AAA",
                  "price":50,
                  "children":null
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "name":"AB",
            "price":766,
            "children":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"B",
      "price":78,
      "children":[  
         {  
            "name":"C",
            "price":150,
            "children":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"C",
      "price":453,
      "children":null
   }
]
```

I have to create nested accordion. But the thing is this nesting is never ending. A children can have any no. of children, and that children can have any no. of children and so on.

So how will I show it like an accordion in html. I am using Angular.

I was thinking that I can create two separate components for parent and child.

```
  <table>
   <div *ngFor = "let acc of accountList">
      <tr>
         <td>{{ acc.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ acc.price }}</td>
      </tr>
      <div *ngIf = "acc.children?.length">
         <div *ngFor = "let a1 of acc.children">
            <tr>
               <td>{{ a1.name }}</td>
               <td>{{ a1.price }}</td>
               .... and so on
            </tr>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done by nesting the same component with an input property. The template below should give you a hint

```
<ul *ngIf="data">
    <li *ngFor="let item of data">{{item.name}}:{{item.price}}
        <hello [data]="item.children"></hello>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-tree

One thing to keep in mind would be the nesting levels, if they are too deep, it may throw a stack overflow error.